# ValueChangeListener not being invoked upon submit

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

My valuechangelistener method is not being called as I expected. I have a h:selectOneRadio component (below) and I'm expecting the valueChangeListener to be called when I click the add button, but only the add method is getting invoked, the setSelectedItem method is completely ignored. What am I missing? Note the javascript dataTableSelectOneRadio is executing fine.

Here is the .xhtml

```
h:panelGrid
Select Client to Associate with Appointment
<h:dataTable id="addClient" styleClass="dataTable"
   value="#{AddEntryMB.clientValues}" var="c" binding="#{AddEntryMB.dataTable}" >

<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Select</f:facet>
        <h:selectOneRadio valueChangeListener="#{AddEntryMB.setSelectedItem}" 
               immediate="true" onchange="dataTableSelectOneRadio(this);">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="null" />
            </h:selectOneRadio>
</h:column>

<h:column>
   <f:facet name="header">Last Name</f:facet>
    #{c.lastName}
</h:column>

</h:dataTable>
</h:panelGrid>

<h:panelGroup>
    <h:commandButton action="#{AddEntryMB.add}" value="add" />
    <h:commandButton action="cancel" value="cancel" immediate="true"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

And here is the backing bean.

```
@ManagedBean(name="AddEntryMB")
@ViewScoped
public class AddEntryMB implements Serializable {
private int  rowIndex;
private int idValue;
    private transient HtmlDataTable dataTable;

 public void setSelectedItem(ValueChangeEvent event) {

    rowIndex = dataTable.getRowIndex();

}

public void add()
{
    DefaultScheduleEntry entry = new DefaultScheduleEntry();
    entry.setId(RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(32));
    entry.setStartTime(from);
    entry.setEndTime(until);
    entry.setTitle(title);
    entry.setSubtitle(location);
    entry.setDescription(comments);
}
```

Comment: Ahh Ha! I changed the scope to Session and all of a sudden it works! Is there a list somewhere that explains what will and will not work with ViewScope?

Comment: Also, does anyone understand why ViewScope would have this effect?

Answer (score 0):

The view scoped bean will be recreated during every RESTORE_VIEW phase when you bind a component by `binding` to a property of the view scoped bean. This is known as [JSF issue 1492](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1492) and fixed for the upcoming JSF 2.2.

In this particular case, you'd better remove `binding="#{AddEntryMB.dataTable}"` and grab the current `var="c"` from the EL context.

```
public void setSelectedItem(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    DefaultScheduleEntry c = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{c}", DefaultScheduleEntry.class);
    // ...
}
```